# How to flip, scale and center div from every position

Tags: jquery, html, css, transform

I want to achieve a flipping image which also scales up and centers to the viewport, if it was clicked and this for every image which is of course on different position.
On the back of this image there will be a description and a bigger Image of the same one.
Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Using CSS transitions will be helpful.

Comment: Funny but how can i solve the centering problem?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [**Flippy**](http://guilhemmarty.com/flippy/). It will take care about centering.